# OpenTok API for android

Tags: java, android, api, opentok

I am using OpenTokSamples project for OpenTok API and in that I want to create session id and token id through java code and I implemented the code by calling createSession() method but its throwing error----> Could not find class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper', referenced from method com.opentok.OpenTok.. I searched a lot and found need to add Jackson-databind jar & Jackson-annotations jar but still the issue is not getting resolved. Please help me on this.

Comment: you should not be trying to create sessions or tokens from Android. the README.md shows that you should be creating the session and token (either in the Dashboard, or using a Server SDK outside of the OpenTokSamples project) and placing those values in OpenTokConfig.java.

Comment: can you please paste the link where its written "using a Server SDK outside of the OpenTokSamples project"

Answer (score 0):

There is another Jackson jar which implements the json<->object mappers.
This jar is jackson-mapper-XXX.jar [1]

If you check the repo [2], it comes with gradle support pointing to the dependencies it needs to build.

[1] http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/

[2] https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK

Comment: I have tried by importing that jar too but its still throwing that error. For your information, I am using Eclipse IDE and not using maven.

Answer (score 0):

You are meant to create sessions and tokens using the OpenTok Server SDKs, not on clients (such as Android).

It sounds like you are most familiar with Java as a language, so I suggest using the [OpenTok Java SDK](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK) and running it on a server. There is a very easy to understand [HelloWorld tutorial](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK/tree/master/sample/HelloWorld) in the samples directory, with instructions on how to use it in the README.md file. It will guide you to get the server running locally on your development machine.

An even more useful example might the [Learning OpenTok tutorial for Android](https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-android). It shows how to send a request to a server that returns the session ID and token. The server used in this tutorial is written in PHP, but for your convenience there is a one-click button for starting your own server on Heroku (instead of locally on your development machine).

I hope this provides you all the information you need to start generating sessions and tokens dynamically! Let me know how that turns out, and feel free to give feedback on the tutorials as GitHub Issues in those repositories.